# Firebase SDK Generation of the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml failed

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

So, I don't know if this is the place to post this, but I already posted in the Github page of the project SDK's and no one answered, so I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

I am trying to do Authentication and Analytics through Firebase SDK's for Unity. I followed all the footsteps listed in their documentation and got it to work at some level.

The Auth is working. I can register new users, and it is giving me the correct errorCodes (Exceptions).
Here it's where it gets weird. Some Basic functions of unity stopped working like changing scene, changing texts dynamically, etc..

This is the error I keep getting:

Generation of the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml from Assets/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist failed.

If you have not included a valid Firebase Android resources in your app it will fail to initialize.

"python" "/Users/xxxxx/Documents/ProgrammingCloud/Unity/yyyyy/Assets/Firebase/Editor/generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py" -i "Assets/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist" -l --plist

Could not find key in plist file: [DATABASE_URL]

You can start to diagnose this issue by executing ""python" "/Users/xxxxx/Documents/ProgrammingCloud/Unity/yyyyy/Assets/Firebase/Editor/generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py" -i "Assets/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist" -l --plist" from the command line.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)

Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:RunResourceGenerator(IEnumerable`1, String, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DPw5MV1I7c/firebase/app/client/unity/editor/src/GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:542)

Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:ReadBundleIds(String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DPw5MV1I7c/firebase/app/client/unity/editor/src/GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:407)

Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:UpdateConfigFileDirectory() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DPw5MV1I7c/firebase/app/client/unity/editor/src/GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:295)

Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:CheckConfiguration() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DPw5MV1I7c/firebase/app/client/unity/editor/src/GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:246)

Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DPw5MV1I7c/firebase/app/client/unity/editor/src/GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:103)

Google.c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Ujmedx6O9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/EditorInitializer.cs:60)

Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Ujmedx6O9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:409)

Google.RunOnMainThread:m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Ujmedx6O9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:541)

Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Ujmedx6O9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)

Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested(Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Ujmedx6O9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)

Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.Ujmedx6O9O/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)

UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:332)

This is the post in the GitHub page:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/892

I would appreciate some help. Getting pretty desperate, I've been on this all day long.

Comment: I see that the GitHub problem has been answered, has that helped?

Answer (score 0):

A `GoogleService-Info.plist` contains the configuration information for an **iOS** app to communicate with a Firebase project, but you say that you're building an **Android** app. Are you sure you defined the correct type of app, and added the correct configuration file to the Android Studio project?

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a database within the Firebase console and downloading the plist file again. Doing so added an extra line with the URL needed to make the link between the file and console.